# How to list all relations and foreign keys in for all models in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I need a script which writes to csv displaying all models names, foreign keys and relationship with other models(if any.)

How to get all models and how do I list a the foreign key field and model it is referencing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get all models :

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.all()
```

to get foreign keys:

```
for field in ModelName._meta.fields:
    if field.get_internal_type() == 'ForeignKey':
        print (field)
```